# How to find already exists values in xml

Tags: c#, xml

Hello everyone I want to update one `xml` data to another using `c#`. For this I First I have to check if  that `xml` data exists in another `xml` or not. I stuck in this code please help me how can I complete this ? Here is my code

```
protected void CheckUpdates()
{
    XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
    XmlNodeList xmlnode;
    int i = 0;
    string str = null;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("..\\xml\\listUpdates.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    xmldoc.Load(fs);
    xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("lst");
    for (i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim();
        str = xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim() ;
    }
}
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<blocker>
  <lst>Download</lst>
  <lst>Downloader</lst>
  <lst>Downloader</lst>
  <lst>Downloader</lst>
  <lst>video</lst>
  <lst>video</lst>
</blocker>
```

In this code first I retrieve  the data from the new xml and now I want to check in my old xml that if value already exists or not then i will update it Please tell me what I have to do next 
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. How your xml file (or files) look like? What exactly you are checking here?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy see I have one xml file with some new values. that i want to add in my old xml check how my xml file look like.. I edit my question

Answer (score 0):

You want to parse new XML files and add any values in `lst` elements that are not yet included in your existing XML file. Here's the code doing this:

var originalXmlDoc = XDocument.Load(originalFilename);
var newXmlDoc = XDocument.Load(newFilename);

```
foreach (var newElement in newXmlDoc.Element("blocker").Elements("lst"))
{
    newElement.Value.Trim().Dump();
    if (!originalXmlDoc.Element("blocker").Elements("lst")
                  .Any(oldElement => oldElement.Value.Trim().Equals(
                      newElement.Value.Trim(), 
                      StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
    {
        originalXmlDoc.Element("blocker").Add(new XElement("lst", newElement.Value));
    }
}
originalXmlDoc.Save(originalFilename, SaveOptions.None);
```

You can try it out with the following 2 XML files:

Original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<blocker>
  <lst>Downloader</lst>
</blocker>
```

New XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<blocker>
  <lst>Download</lst>
  <lst>Downloader</lst>
  <lst>Downloader</lst>
  <lst>Downloader</lst>
  <lst>video</lst>
  <lst>video</lst>
</blocker>
```

Resulting XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<blocker>
  <lst>Downloader</lst>
  <lst>Download</lst>
  <lst>video</lst>
</blocker>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using XmlDocument:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("original.xml");

    XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
    doc2.Load("update.xml");

    var nodesoriginal = doc.SelectNodes("/blocker/lst");
    var nodesupdate = doc2.SelectNodes("/blocker/lst");

    var List = nodesoriginal.Cast<XmlNode>().Concat<XmlNode>(nodesupdate.Cast<XmlNode>());

    foreach (XmlNode element in List)
    {
        string value = element.InnerText;
        if (value != null && !set.Contains(value))
        {
            set.Add(value);
        }
    }

    XmlDocument output = new XmlDocument();
    XmlElement blocker = output.CreateElement("blocker");
    foreach(var str in set)
    {
        XmlElement node = output.CreateElement("lst");
        node.InnerText = str;
        blocker.AppendChild(node);
    }

    output.AppendChild(blocker);

    output.Save("output.xml");
    output.Save(Console.Out);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

original.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<blocker>
<lst>Original1</lst>
</blocker>
```

update.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<blocker>
 <lst>Download</lst>
 <lst>Downloader</lst>
 <lst>Downloader</lst>
 <lst>Downloader</lst>
 <lst>video</lst>
 <lst>video</lst>
</blocker>
```

output xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm852"?>
<blocker>
  <lst>Original1</lst>
  <lst>Download</lst>
  <lst>Downloader</lst>
  <lst>video</lst>
</blocker>
```